# How to disable (or change color) of 2nd drop down option depenging on 1st selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is "how to change an options color (or disable) within a second drop down list depending on a first selection?" with javascript / jquery.

For example: If selected "13 Stairs" in my first drop down list 14 and 15 Stairs should have color "red" ***(or disabled)*** in the second drop down.

Something like "if option==13 Stairs* -> 14* / 15* == disabled" or
"if selected value "a" -> value "m-r" = red."

Perhaps its very easy, but I'm a completly nood in Javascript. :(
Hopefully someone can hep me.

```
<form id="test" name="test" method="post" action="">
    <label for="demo"></label>
    <select name="first-election" id="first-election">
      <option value="a">13 Stairs - 001</option>
      <option value="b">13 Stairs - 002</option>
      <option value="c">13 Stairs - 003</option>
      <option value="d">14 Stairs - 001</option>
      <option value="e">14 Stairs - 002</option>
      <option value="f">14 Stairs - 003</option>
      <option value="g">15 Stairs - 001</option>
      <option value="h">15 Stairs - 002</option>
      <option value="i">15 Stairs - 003</option>
    </select>
<br /><br />
    <select name="color" id="color">
      <option value="j">13 Stairs - green</option>
      <option value="k">13 Stairs - yellow</option>
      <option value="l">13 Stairs - black</option>
      <option value="m">14 Stairs - green</option>
      <option value="n">14 Stairs - yellow</option>
      <option value="o">14 Stairs - black</option>
      <option value="p">15 Stairs - green</option>
      <option value="q">15 Stairs - yellow</option>
      <option value="r">15 Stairs - black</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: You cannot set the color of `option`s in a `select` element.

Comment: but perhaps disable them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to `disable` the `option`s:

```
var $options = $('#color').find('option');

$('#first-election').change(function () {

    var num = parseInt( $('option:selected', this).text(), 10 );

    $options.prop('disabled', false).filter(function () {
        return $.text(this).indexOf(num) !== 0;
    }).prop('disabled', true);

}).change();
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gp7fF/

Comment: This function reads the first 10 characters of an option and then disables them within the 2nd #colors right? Any idea how to look up "a phrase"?

Answer (score 0):

unless you write your own custom select object (made of Divs and built to look like a stock select but not using the standard browser object) you can't set some items to one color and other items to another.  However, you can re-draw your entire selector to have whatever fields you want, so your second approach (of hiding the elements that are no longer relevant) is entirely feasible.

You'll want to use the onSelect callback and put it in the first dropdown and then write a function that changes the contents of the second dropdown based on what item the user selects in the first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it. Look at this example :
http://jsfiddle.net/TxbVt/773

HTML :

```
<select>
    <option>1111111</option>
    <option>222222222</option>
    <option>33333333</option>
    <option>44444444</option>
</select>
```

JS :

```
var options = document.getElementsByTagName('option');
for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i += 1) {
    var option = options[i];
    var colors = ['blue','yellow','purple','brown'];
    $(option).css('background-color',colors[i]);
}
```

Click the select form, the options have different colors.